# What will happen if I accept this "Change your search setting to: smartwebfinder.com"?

Tags: authentication, passwords, network, web-browser

When I want to install Ultrasurf extension it gives me this message:

[image]

So I do not understand what this "Change your search setting to: smartwebfinder.com" wants to do.

When I go to this website : `smartwebfinder.com` it redirects me to `google.com`

Why does it return `google.com` to me when I go to that website?

What will happen if I accept this "Change your search setting to: smartwebfinder.com"?

Comment: surfing keys extension just added that search out of nowhere

Answer (score 2):

> What will happen if I accept this "Change your search setting to: smartwebfinder.com"?

It will change your search settings to this site. While this site might currently just redirect to google.com it can change this behavior any time without your control. Thus, if you don't actually need it simply don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this extension came with other software. I never heard of this extension but some extensions can be malware, it says on the actual extension on your screenshot what it can do. "read and change your data on websites". just because it loads google after, doesn't mean it isn't logging your data anyway.